# text split problem

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a program which scans trough a textbox1 text and displays all words from textbox1 which are more than n letters long in textbox2. Here's the complete code:

```
Private Function filterWords(ByVal minLenght As Short, ByVal input As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim strInput() As String = input.Split(" ")
        Dim strList As New List(Of String)
        strList = strInput.ToList()

        For Each word In strInput
            If word.Length < minLenght Then
                strList.Remove(word)
            End If
        Next
        Return strList
    End Function

    Private Sub textbox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles textbox1.TextChanged
        textbox2.Text = ""
        Dim strOut As New List(Of String)

        strOut = filterWords(4, textbox1.Text)

        For Each w In strOut
            textbox2.Text += w & " "
        Next
    End Sub
```

If you for example type *a b c d* then it will not show anything in textbox2, but if you type *a* then press enter and then *b*, it will show both of them. What should I write to avoid this?

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow, if you type a b c d then nothing will show in textbox2 because all of the words are less than the required length which is 4? except if a b c d is sample words that might have a length of > 4 then I can't see anything wrong?

Comment: Do you want this to happen as the user types or rather once the user is finished typing? i.e. pressed enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on how you define a word. Your current implementation defines that a space donates the end of a word. You define this by only passing the space to `input.Split`. If you also want to define that a period (.) ends a word, add it: `input.Split(" .")`.
If you want to make a word end on a new line, add it: `input.Split(" ." & Environment.NewLine.ToString())`.

An alternative approach would be to use regular expressions, maybe like so:

```
Private Function filterWords(ByVal minLength As Short, ByVal input As String) _
    As List(Of String)

    Dim strList As New List(Of String)
    Dim wordMatches = Regex.Matches(input, "\w+").Cast(Of Match)
    For Each wordMatch In wordMatches
        If wordMatch.Value.Length >= minLength Then
            strList.Add(wordMatch.Value)
        End If
    Next
    Return strList

End Function
```

Comment: How to get Regex? What I should import?

Comment: `Import System.Text.RegularExpressions`